# A non well formed numeric value encountered - Can not reproduce

Tags: php, php-7.1

I am getting an error I cannot reproduce.

The following code is part of a module which protects against attacks. This particular snippet is tracking how many hits from a particular bot user agent I am getting.

After many years of trouble free use, I am all of a sudden getting the error:

> A non well formed numeric value encountered;

This is occurring at the line:

```
    $seconds = time() - $time;
```

The value of $time is `2016-10-02 19:33:42`

the function safefilename() returns:

> Mozilla-5-0-compatible-spbot-5-0-3-http-OpenLinkProfiler-org-bot

The name of the file being written to and read is:

> bot_2016-10-02--19-33-42_Mozilla-5-0-compatible-spbot-5-0-3-http-Open_104.131.179.5.log

**Methodology**

The code below targets bots and writes to a filename which is based on the user agent and the time the file was created. Each time that user agent is used, it adds an "X" to the file so I can keep track of how many times that agent has visited. If a bot is targeting me more than a certain number of times, I block it.

The code below produces the desire outcome in testing and in production - except of course when this error is thrown. The file mentioned has 6 bytes written to it, so it has been read and written to successfully 5 times before.

The php error was logged at 06:37:04 and my server log file shows these hits:

`104.131.63.140 - - [10/Dec/2016:06:36:59 -0800] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 301 257 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; spbot/5.0.3; +http://OpenLinkProfiler.org/bot )"`

`104.131.63.140 - - [10/Dec/2016:06:36:59 -0800] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 1460 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; spbot/5.0.3; +http://OpenLinkProfiler.org/bot )"`

`104.131.63.140 - - [10/Dec/2016:06:37:04 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 937 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; spbot/5.0.3; +http://OpenLinkProfiler.org/bot )"`

`104.131.63.140 - - [10/Dec/2016:06:37:05 -0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 247 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; spbot/5.0.3; +http://OpenLinkProfiler.org/bot )"`

**PHP Code**
I've extracted the following code which can be run stand alone to test.

```
// this is my site address
define("STATIC_SITE_ROOT", "http://static"); 

$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; spbot/5.0.3; +http://OpenLinkProfiler.org/bot )";
$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$t = new test();
$t->testAgent($agent, $ip);

class test {
    public $agent;
    public $ip;
    public $maxbadpages = 100;

    function testAgent($agent, $ip){
        $this->agent = $agent;
        $this->ip = $ip;

        if (strlen($badbot = $this->badbot($this->agent)) > 0){
            $new = FALSE;
            $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/logs";
            // $filename = "bot-" . time() . "-" . safefilename(substr($this->agent, 0, 50));
            $safefilename = safefilename(substr($this->agent, 0, 50));
            $filename = "bot_" . date("Y-m-d--H-i-s") . "_" . $safefilename . "_" . $this->ip . ".log";
            $filter = $safefilename;
            $afiles = getDirArray($path, $filter);
            if (count($afiles) > 0){
                // bot file already exists
                $filename = $afiles[0];     
            } else {
                // add time to filename if crating new file
                $new = TRUE;
            }
            $fullfilename = "$path/$filename";

            // log a counter (# bytes in file)
            file_put_contents($fullfilename, "X", FILE_APPEND);

            // number of hits == size of file
            $size = filesize($fullfilename);

            // count hits to determine if block via htaccess
            // if > # entries in log from a useragent, ban it
            if ($size > $this->maxbadpages){
                $this->blockagent($this->agent, $this->ip, "> $this->maxbadpages hits");
            } elseif (! $new) {
                // test for hits per second
                $blockagent = FALSE;
                $parts = explode("_", $filename);
                // 2nd part is the time
                // $time = strtotime($parts[1]);
                $parts2 = explode("--", $parts[1]);
                $time = $parts2[0] . " " . str_replace("-",":",$parts2[1]);
                // seconds is time elapsed
                $seconds = time() - $time;
                // check for various scenarios
                if ($size > $seconds * 2){
                    // more than average of 2 hits per second for any period
                    $blockagent = TRUE;
                    $reason = "$size (hits) > $seconds (seconds) * 2";
                }
                if ($seconds >= 10 && $size > $seconds * 1){
                    // more than 1 hit per second over 10 seconds
                    $blockagent = TRUE;
                    $reason = "$seconds (seconds) >= 10 && $size (hits) > $seconds (seconds) * 1";
                }
                if ($blockagent){
                    $this->blockagent($this->agent, $this->ip, $reason);            
                }
            }       
            $this->blockAccess("bad bot: ". $badbot);
        }
    }

    function blockAgent($message){
        die("Block Agent: " . $message);
    }

    function blockAccess($message){
        die("Block Access: " . $message);
    }

    function badbot($agent) {
        if (stripos($agent, "bot") !==FALSE){
            return "match 'bot' in agent: ($agent)";
        } elseif (stripos($agent, "spider") !==FALSE){
            return "match 'spider' in agent: ($agent)";
        } elseif (stripos($agent, "crawl") !==FALSE){
            return "match 'crawl' in agent: ($agent)";
        }
        $badbots = array(
        "007AC9",
        "2Bone",
        "404 Checker",
        "There are many more bad bots contained in this array...");

        foreach ($badbots as $bot) {
            //If the spider text is found in the current user agent, then return true
            if (stripos($agent, $bot) !== false){
                return "$bot ($agent)";
                return "match: $bot in agent: ($agent)";
            }
        }
        //If it gets this far then no bot was found!
        return "";
    }


}


function safefilename($string){
    // convert entities e.g. Á => &Aacute;
    $string = htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');    

    // replace the entities with letter equivalents
    $string = preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', $string);

    // return entities which did not have letter equivalents back to entities
    $string = html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

    // replace non valid chars with dash and multiple dashes with only one
    $string = preg_replace(array('~[^0-9a-z]~i', '~[ -]+~'), '-', $string);

    return trim($string, ' -');
}


function getDirArray($path = "./", $filter = ".*", $exclude = '', $sorted = true, $optfilter2 = '') {
    // for server directories, can't use the static url
    $path = str_replace(STATIC_SITE_ROOT, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], $path);
    if (file_exists($path) == false) {
    if (mkdir($path, 0777, true) == false) {
        die($path);
        exit;
    }
    }

    $handle = opendir($path);
    $dir = array();
    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
    if (is_file("$path/$file") && preg_match("/$filter/", $file) && (strlen($exclude) == 0 ? TRUE : !preg_match("/$exclude/", $file))) {
        if ($optfilter2 == '') {
        // No 2n filter
        $dir[] = $file;
        } else {
        $pos = strpos($file, $optfilter2);
        if ($pos === false) {
            // Not found
        } else {
            $dir[] = $file;
        }
        }
    }
    }
    closedir($handle);

    if ($sorted == true) {
    sort($dir);
    }

    return $dir;
}
```

Comment: Your `$parts2 = explode("--", $parts[1]);` is not what you expect, I suppose

Comment: @Federkun Production: `PHP Version 7.1.0RC4` Test Server: `PHP Version 7.0.9`

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($time);`?

Comment: Which php version are you using?

Comment: @bugfroggy - time returns `2016-10-02 19:33:42`

Comment: @u_mulder $parts2 returns `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2016-10-02"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "19-33-42"
}`

Comment: @mseifert try using this: `$seconds = time() - strtotime($time);`. I suspect the issue is that `$time` is a string.

Comment: @bugfroggy - You are correct - `time() - $time` returns 
int(1481397346) while `time() - strtotime($time)` returns int(5937340). I can't figure out exactly what conversion is going on exactly, but clearly this is it.

Comment: @bugfroggy If you want to post this as the answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was you were using a datetime string rather than a unix timestamp. You needed to use, as suggested in my comment, `strtotime($time)` to fix this, but you don't seem to understand why.

From the documentation for `time`:

> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

This means when you are executing `time()` it is returning the number of seconds-- an **integer**-- since New Years of 1970 in GMT timezone.

On the other hand, you had `$time`, which was a **string.** This string is a more user-friendly string that can be read rather than an integer representing a number of seconds. There are some cases where you need this string rather than a unix timestamp, although that was not the case this time.

You were trying to subtract `$time` (string) from `time()` (integer). This obviously will not work, as you cannot subtract a letter from a number, and that's why you were getting that error. `strtotime` is a function that is able to parse a date as a string such as the one you provided and convert it into an integer of how many seconds since New Years of 1970.

In your comment you said, after encasing `$time` in `strtotime()`, that you are now getting `5937340` as the result. This is the difference in seconds between the current time and `$time`. Hopefully this is what you were looking for. It is equivalent to approximately 68.7 days. If this is not the result you expected, then I can try to help you further.

It is also possible to subtract two date strings from each other using the `DateTime` class but it is more complicated and unnecessary in your situation in my opinion. You cannot, though, subtract an integer date from a string date. They have to be converted to be the same type. Hopefully I helped clear this up for you.